# Make uploaded images draggable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make uploaded images draggable, can anyone help me please?

Item 1 and Item 2 are nicely draggable, but images are just like one Item for dragging, so I can drag for example 3 images, but not separately..

There is javascript code

```
    window.onload = function(){

    //Check File API support
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader){
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("files"); 
        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("result");

            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++){
                var file = files[i]; 
                //Only pics
                if(!file.type.match('image'))
                  continue;                
                var picReader = new FileReader();                
                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){                    
                    var picFile = event.target;                    
                    var div = document.createElement("div");                    
                    div.innerHTML = "<li class='ui-state-default'><img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +"title='" + picFile.name + "'/></li>";                    
                    output.insertBefore(div,null);                            
                });              
                 //Read the image
                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }                                        
        });
    }
    else{
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
```

Html looks like:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
<output id="result" />
</ul>
```

Comment: Tip: use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using FileReader

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make your elements draggable, sortable and much more.
you can use jquery-ui. its very smart jquery plugin.

I hope It will help you.

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Sure, I did it via jquerry, but it does not solve my problem. Anyway, thank you for your answer..!